# How to add a context menu for only one level in a TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a TreeView, containing a number of levels of `TreeViewItems`.

I would like to add a context menu to only one level of items in the TreeView. However, my code produces a result whereby every single item in the TreeView has a context menu.

This is my code:

```
//.... foreach item in this level.... 

{
ContextMenu cmDatabase = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
menuItem.Header = "Close Connection";
Image imgMenuIcon = new Image();
imgMenuIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("icon.png"));
menuItem.Icon = imgMenuIcon;
cmDatabase.Items.Add(menuItem);
treeViewItem.ContextMenu = cmDatabase;
}
```

I've also tried manually setting all the other TreeViewItems' contextMenu property to null.  No luck though.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TreeView` has a `ContextMenuOpening` event. Set the `Handled` property of the event handler argument `e` to `true` depending on the tree level. This will discard the context menu.

```
private void treeView1_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = <tree level does not require a context menu>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a TextBlock for your TreeViewItem, you can attach the ContextMenu onto that instead.

```
 Textblock header = "TreeViewItem Text";
 header.ContextMenu = cmDataBase;
 treeViewItem.Header = header;
```

Also, for your other question that I answered, but you deleted before I hit Save. :P I'd put the right-click as an event (also on the header).

```
 header.MouseRightButtonDown += new MousebuttonEventHandler(rightClickSelection);

 private void rightclickSelection(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
      TreeViewItem clickedParent = (sender as TextBlock).Parent as TreeViewItem;
      clickedParent.IsSelected = true;
      clickedParent.UpdateLayout();
 }
```

Comment: +1 for your answer. Olivier's solution worked and since I tried his first, I was unable to try yours. I however greatly appreciate the effort, so thanks for that! :)

Comment: @DotNET No worries, buddy. I had to customize the look/feel of my TreeViewItem, which is why I used an object for the TreeViewItem header instead of straight text, which figure out this trick. :)